# i see "405: Method Not Allowed" when trying following code on Python 3.8.3

Tags: aiohttp, python-3.8

## https://tutorialedge.net/python/create-rest-api-python-aiohttp/

from aiohttp import web
import json

```
async def handle(request):
    response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj))


async def new_user(request):
    try:
        print("AT Epoint" )
        ## happy path where name is set
        user = request.query['name']
        ## Process our new user
        print("Creating new user with name: " , user)

        response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
        ## return a success json response with status code 200 i.e. 'OK'
        return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status=200)
    except Exception as e:
        print("AT EXCEPTION" )
        ## Bad path where name is not set
        response_obj = { 'status' : 'failed', 'reason': str(e) }
        ## return failed with a status code of 500 i.e. 'Server Error'
        return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have implemented the listener function, register it with the `aiohttp` instance.

```py
app.router.add_post('/user', new_user)
```

Source: [TutorialEdge](https://tutorialedge.net/python/create-rest-api-python-aiohttp/)

Comment: I have added that already. It happens at runtime. Try it yourself with that version of python

Comment: I have implemented new_user. This happens at runtime. That is not the answer I am looking for. Try it yourself;